# Upgrading FlurryAPI+AppCircle to FlurryAds in iOS gives following linker errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, flurry

While Customizing an old app, I updated flurry which was already integrated before.

Also converted FlurryAPI+AppCircle.h to FlurryAds.h

But a file consisting FlurryOffer.h which just have declarations don't even have any link to these FlurryAds.h

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurryOffer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CustomAppCircleViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

*FlurryOffer.h*

```
    //  FlurryOffer.h
    //  Flurry iPhone Analytics Agent
    //
    //  Copyright 2010 Flurry, Inc. All rights reserved.

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface FlurryOffer : NSObject {
        NSString* appName;
        UIImage* appIcon;
        NSString* referralUrl;
        NSNumber* appPrice;
        NSString* appDescription;
    }

    @property (retain) NSString* appName;
    @property (retain) UIImage* appIcon;
    @property (retain) NSString* referralUrl;
    @property (retain) NSNumber* appPrice;
    @property (retain) NSString* appDescription;

    @end
```